# Why do I have PermissionError: [WinError 5] in Python?

Tags: python, permissionerror

Whenever I run my script, I get `PermissionError: [WinError 5] access denied`, unless I delete the target folder `tuner_dir`, and re-run the code. Here some of the code:

```
# Check if the tuner directory exists and is empty
if os.path.exists(tuner_dir) and not os.listdir(tuner_dir):
    print(f"The tuner directory '{tuner_dir}' is empty.")
else:
    print(f"The tuner directory '{tuner_dir}' is not empty or doesn't exist.")
    # Check the reset_tuner flag and optionally delete the contents of the directory
    if reset_tuner:
        for item in os.listdir(tuner_dir):
            item_path = os.path.join(tuner_dir, item)
            if os.path.isfile(item_path):
                os.remove(item_path)
                print(f"Removed file: {item_path}")
            elif os.path.isdir(item_path):  # Change to 'os.path.isdir'
                shutil.rmtree(item_path)
                print(f"Removed directory: {item_path}")

#The code continues on.
```

These are the only lines in the code that rever to this problematic `tuner_dir`. I have checked user rights for groups and users, I have a single user in my PC (only me), I run Python as Administrator by default (after looking for ways to solve this problem), and in *Properties > Security* I see Authenticated Users, System, Administrators and my own user with full rights in this working directory. I don't know what else to do. Everytime I need to manually delete the folder, and re-run the code, and while this is a workaround.

This is the resulting icacls over the target directory:

```
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code in your example? It is not clear where the error is thrown, what directories are needed to run the script and what paths in the conditionals are taken.